# logical and physical address spaces in in the execution-time address-binding scheme

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I was reading an operating system book and I found the following information which I couldn't understand :

> Logical and physical addresses are the same in compile-time and
> load-time address-binding schemes; logical (virtual) and physical
> addresses differ in execution-time address-binding scheme".

so does it mean that in the compile-time address-binding which converts symbolic addresses to physical address or to relocatable addresses and in load-time address-binding which converts relocatable addresses to physical address , the program deals with physical addresses and the CPU generates the physical address directly ?!

and in execution-time address-binding scheme in which the location of the program in main memory may change so there would be separated address spaces ?!

is that the idea or Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which operating system text are you reading from; ie. what date?

Traditional UNIX tools comprised a compiler (ccN), which converted source into asm; an assembler (as), which converted asm into either relocatable object code or executable; and a loader (ld) which combined object code files into a resolved executable.

Note that the assembler, if all symbols were resolved, could create an executable: the convention `a.out` is an artifact of this.

Other systems, notably IBM mainframes and later MSDOS, referred to `loading` as `link editting`, a difference without distinction.

When `ld` resolved (assigned) addresses to the executable, those addresses were *virtual*; although in practice might have been *physical*.  Ld didn't care, its job was to combine N object files into a fully resolved executable, perhaps guided by rules like:  `.text = 0x0, .data = .text + size(.text), ...`.  If I had an embedded system with only physical addresses, I could guide `ld` with other rules.

The resultant, `a.out` has a notion of the addresses of everything, and on modern equipment (where modern means any significant computer since 1978) these are virtual addresses, which the operating system which *maps* the executable into memory resolves to other physical memory addresses.

In more modern system, (since circa 2003), the `a.out` does not contain exact addresses, rather contains *relative addresses* and internal mapping tables.  This enables operating systems to change a programs addresses each time they are run to thwart some simple malware attacks.